# ios YTPlayerView does not respond to touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, uicollectionview

I have a problem with YTPlayerView, I created a collection view, and in each cell is added subview YTPlayerView, the problem is that it shows great, but does not respond to pressing on view  etc.

Not working on thumbnail page, when video playing  all's fine.
[How it's looking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPl67.jpg)
    #pragma mark UICollectionView

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return self.dataSource.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
            cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

YTCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.identifierDataSource[indexPath.row]
                                                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [YTCollectionViewCell new];
}
if (!cell.loaded) {
    [cell.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
    cell.loaded = YES;
}
return cell;}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
YTCollectionViewCell* ycell = (YTCollectionViewCell*)cell;
[ycell.playerView stopVideo];}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
YTCollectionViewCell* ycell = (YTCollectionViewCell*)cell;

if (!ycell.loaded) {
    [ycell.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
    ycell.loaded = YES;
}else{
//[ycell.playerView playVideo];
}
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Thank you. True, I did not quite understand what the problem is. Moreover, if the call methods startplaying, the video load and runs. So as I understand it, the matter is to press. But not quite understand what could be the reason. I can add code?

Comment: Sure you can, edit the post by adding the control and event related code, that could be a start. Otherwise it's way too difficult to help as the amount of reasons may be many.

Comment: YTPlayerView open in Video Controller manner and you want to touch on done button or where you want touch ?